# Laravel/Lumen The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm getting the following error when trying to return a json response with Lumen.

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

After looking around on here it seems people where getting this error when not returning a string so json_encode in the Illuminate\Http\Response fails. However I'm definitely returning a string.

I'm taking user input for a database connection then testing the connection and if there is an error returning that.

```
try{
  $connection = new \PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
  return true;
}catch(\Exception $e){
  return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

At this point I get the above error. I do a dd() on $e->getMessage() I'm getting a string I expected.

```
string(53) "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test-db'"
```

Why am I still getting the error when I'm returning an array of with a string?

Comment: You are returning a boolean on success...

Comment: @TJMonk15 yes that is correct, if the function returns true then I send the appropriate response back. However if there is an exception I return the JSON response so it shouldn't be returning true should it?

Comment: We seem to be missing some code then. What code calls this code and returns the response?